# Difficulties using Windows Installer to Deploy a COM Add-In

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2012, com, windows-installer

I created a COM Add-In in Visual Studio 2012 and when I compile and run it on my machine, it works perfectly. The problem arises when I try to use the Windows Installer I created to install the Add-In. I am trying to install this Add-In to multiple machines and I would like to figure out that the issue is with the installer.

When I try to call a Sub from the COM Add-In with Excel, it throws a 'Subscript out of range' on the second line. The Sub connects to a SQL server, performs a query based on cell data, and returns the result. I looked at the Add-Ins in Excel, it is installed and not inactive/disabled. This same code works perfectly if I compile the project on my machine, just not when I install the Add-In with the installer.

```
Dim com as COMAddIn
Set com = Application.COMAddIns("SQL")  <----
com.Object.ConStr
```

I followed this guide for the installer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc442767.aspx

I did the following to get the installer running (just a summary of the above article):

- Added the Primary Output, .vsto, and dll.manifest files to the
  application files
- Added .NET Framework 4.5 (full) and Visual Studio 2010 Tools for
  Office Runtime as prerequisites
- Set the INSTALLDIR
- Specified that the application should deploy to the current user
- Told the installer to create the following registry path

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\JACOB.SQL
  ```
- Created the following registry keys

  ```
  Description   SQL
  FriendlyName  SQL
  LoadBehavior  3
  Manifest      file:///[INSTALLDIR]SQL.vsto|vstolocal
  ```
- Set the Build to SingleImage
- Set the InstallShield Prerequisites to 'Download from the Web'
- Set the Active solution configuration to SingleImage
- Set the Configuration of the installer to SingleImage
- Built the Installer

I made sure to uninstall the compiled version of my project from Excel then went to the following file path and ran setup.exe.

```
%Visual Studio 2012%\Projects\SQL\Setup1\SQL_Setup\Express\SingleImage\
DiskImages\DISK1
```

After the installer completed, I ran the same code as above and it returned a 'Subscript out of range' error. As I said earlier, the same code works if I compile the code.

```
Dim com as COMAddIn
Set com = Application.COMAddIns("SQL")  <----
com.Object.ConStr
```

I have researched what the issue may be and have come up mostly blank. I have found that I may need DllRegisterServer/DllUnregisterServer methods to add my dll to the registry with Regsvr32, but I have no idea how to write these methods. I also don't see how this could be the issue if the compiled project works without these methods. Maybe the installer skips a step?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing it on another machine manually without the installer?  It may be the installer has nothing to do with your problem.  Try to install manually on another machine first.

Comment: I tried installing it on another machine and it returned the same error. I also tried creating the registry keys by hand and placing the files in the proper location, no luck. Any advice?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with your installer. Ask a separate question with issues related to putting in another machine